# Is $f(\beta_1 e_1+\dots+\beta_n e_n)=\beta_1 a_1+\dots+\beta_n a_n $ surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

If we have $f:V_1\to V_2$ is linear

and $(e_1,..,e_n)$ be basis for $V_1$

$a_1,..,a_n$ be arbitrary elements from $V_2$

then is $f(\beta_1e_1+..,+\beta_ne_n)=\beta_1a_1+..+\beta_na_n$  surjective?

My thoughts.

When $(a_1,..,a_n)$ is basis for $V_2$ it is clear that it is surjective.

lets take $(a_1,..,a_n)=(0,0,..,0)$ we get that $\beta_1e_1+..,+\beta_ne_n \in \ker(f)$

So $\dim(\ker f)=\dim(V_1)$
from which $\dim \text{Im}(f)=0$ so from this follows that only $\theta_2\in \text{Im}(f)$ ? which has preimage so it is surjective.

Comment: [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) also works in titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the set $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ does not span $V_2$, then $f(V_1)=\operatorname{span}(\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\})\ne V_2$, and therefore $f$ is not surjective.

And if $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ spans $V_2$, then any element of $V_2$ can be written as $\beta_1a_1+\cdots+\beta_na_n$ for some scalars $\beta_1,\beta_2,\cdots,\beta_n$, and therefore $\beta_1a_1+\cdots+\beta_na_n=f(\beta_1e_1+\cdots+\beta_ne_n)$. So, $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Thank you but what's wrong with my work?

Comment: There are many possibilities between $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ being a basis and every $a_k$ being equal to $0$.

Comment: I don't understand can you please elaborate more?If $a_1,..,a_n$ are arbitrary we can take $(0,..,0)$ then $dim(Im(V_2))=0$.I understand that I did something wrong but where is my mistake?

Comment: I told you in my previous comment. Your answer assumes that $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ is a basis or that each $a_k$ is $0$. That is false.

Answer (score 0):

No, by example, if $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 $ is linear, $a_1 = (1,0,0)$ and $a_2 = (0,1,0)$, then $f(\beta_1 e_1+\beta_2 e_2) = \beta_1 (1,0,0)+\beta_2(0,1,0) = (\beta_1, \beta_2,0)$ is no surjective.